# Sample timestamp C

Tags: c, macos, gcc, timestamp

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to sample timestamps in a Mac OS X 64 bit environment, using the gcc compiler. I read about the TSC register in x86 architectures and HPET for Intel processors, but I can't find a guide to use them. Actually, I tried with the function `gettimeofday()` but I need the precision of nanosecond.

Can anyone lead me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8583395/318716

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3051474/318716

Comment: You will be _incredibly_ unlikely to get a resolution/granularity anywhere near a nanosend. Even those functions that state they return nanoseconds tend to have a much higher granularity (meaning for example it may jump from 0ns to 4000ns without any intervening values). I'd be _very_ interested in why you think you need that sort of granularity.

Comment: Why do you think you need nanosecond resolution of time? I work on delivering real time market updates for 100's of exchanges - we use usec and we cant get most stuff below 20usec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On OS X, you can use the `mach_absolute_time` function to get a high-precision timestamp:

```
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* get timer units */
mach_timebase_info_data_t info;
mach_timebase_info(&info);

/* get timer value */
uint64_t ts = mach_absolute_time();

/* convert to nanoseconds */
ts *= info.numer;
ts /= info.denom;
```

Note that if you are trying to time something, you should perform the final nanosecond conversion on the difference between timestamps (the duration) to avoid overflow problems.

Comment: And what is the resolution of the time returned by mach_absolute_time()

Comment: On my machine, it's 1 nanosecond (`info.numer` and `info.denom` are both equal to 1). The difference between adjacent calls is about 30ns as reported by the function.

Comment: I asked for the spec of the resolution of the timer not the value

Comment: Like many other timer functions, the resolution is platform-dependent. I can't give you a specification. But, it's no reason to downvote the answer.

Comment: See [What is `mach_absolute_time()` based on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450737/what-is-mach-absolute-time-based-on-on-iphone).  See also [Quick Performance Measurements](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/03/quick-performance-measurements/).

Comment: @nneonneo It is a perfectly reasonable to downvote your answer. Because it is just wrong. a) you cannot guarantee that resolution on a Mac b) you cannot guarantee is on any other platform. Read the OP's question "but I need the precision of nanosecond." - show me how you provide that

Comment: I *never said* it provides nanosecond accuracy. It's the best timer offered by Mach (the OS X kernel), and on most Macs it does happen to be a nanosecond timer. If you think you can do better, answer the question.